Choosing a nonsingular irreducible member $\sim 2($fiber$+$section$)$ in the Hirzebruch surface $\Sigma_1$
The following is a portion of Example 3.2 in https://projecteuclid.org/journals/kyoto-journal-of-mathematics/volume-31/issue-2/Logarithmic-Enriques-surfaces/10.1215/kjm/1250519795.full.
Let $\pi:\Sigma_1\to \Bbb P^1$ be the $\Bbb P^1$-fibration on a Hirzebruch surface $\Sigma_1$, let $L$ be a general fiber and let $M$ be the $(-1)$-curve of $\Sigma_1$. Take a nonsingular irreducible member $A$ in $|2M+2L|$.
I don't know much about algebraic geometry, and I cannot understand the last sentence. I want to interpret it geometrically/topologically. $\Sigma_1=\Bbb P^2\#\bar{\Bbb P^2}$ can be constructed as follows: Fix a point $p\in \Bbb P^2$ and a line $L=\Bbb P^1\subset \Bbb P^2$ not passing $p$. Let $\Bbb P^2\setminus\{p\}\to L=\Bbb P^1$ be the map defined by $q\mapsto L\cap \overline{pq}$. By blowing up at $p$, we obtain a $\Bbb P^1$-fibration $\Sigma_1=\Bbb P^2\#\bar{\Bbb P^2}\to \Bbb P^1$ with a section given by the exceptional curve. Can I interpret $A$ as follows? Consider a singular conic in $\Bbb P^2$ which has a double point at $p$. Let $A$ be its proper transform. Then its class is $2M+2L$ and $A$ is nonsingular, irreducible, and rational.

Actually, members of $|2M + 2L|$ are the preimages of arbitrary conics on $\mathbb{P}^2$, and if you take a smoth conic not containing $p$, its preimage is smooth.

@Sasha But if a conic does not contain $p$, then isn't its preimage belongs to $|2L|$ instead of $|2L+2M|$?

If $L$ is the class of a general fiber of the projection to $\mathbb{P}^1$, then any member in $|2L|$ is the sum of two fibers.

The surface $\Sigma_1$ is the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at one point $p$. In coloquial terms, $\Sigma_1$ is just $\mathbb{P}^2$ joint a new curve $E$ with the numerical condiction that $E^2=-1$. In your notation, $E=M$.  The Picard group of $\Sigma_1$ is generated by the pull-back of a line $L$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $M$, so any curve $C$ is linearly equivalent to $aL+bM$. So, for any member $A\in |2L+2M|$, it is comming from a conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$, because $2L$ has degree $2$, and this conic is passing throug $p$ with multiplicity $2$. Then, in general the preimage of $A$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a nodal conic passing with multiplicity $2$ at $p$, i.e., are two lines meeting at $p$. Note that I am using that $L$ is the pull-back of a general line in $\mathbb{P}^2$. Now, If $L$ is a general fiber as you want, then the image in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a line passing through $p$ say $L_1$, and any conic $C$ (generic) meet $L_1$ in two points, so any $A\in |2L+2M|$ is comming from some arbitrary conic $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, and the smooth $A's$ are preimages of smooth conics $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$ which do not meet $p$. I apolgize for my misunderstanding with the notation.

Thanks. Is a general member $A$ rational? Under the blow-down $\Sigma_1\to \Bbb P^2$, what is the image of a general  member? Is it a smooth conic?

Note that in the OP's convention $L$ is a general fiber of the projection to $\mathbb{P}^1$, not the preimage of a general line on the plane. So, this answer uses different convention! Moreover, with the convention that $L$ is a preimage of a general line on the plane, one has $(2L + 2M)\cdot M = -2$, hence any member in $|2L + 2M|$ contains $M$ as irreducible component, so the conclusion is wrong.

Yes, @Sasha, you are right I used the wrong notation y by Nakai-Moishezon's Theorem if $L$ is the pull-back of a general line $2L+2M$ is not nef, and so it is not Ample. Thank you.
